# Java Opensource ETL framework with automatic scheduling

Tags: java, frameworks, etl

I am working on the parsing the file data and loading in to the database and this parsing should be repeating for every 5 mins. Is there any Java `ETL` framework which supports automatic job scheduling.

I have exposed to `Talend`. But there  is no automatic job scheduling. My purpose is to schedule parsing jar files for every 5 mins. I cannot depend on the crontab or Windows scheduler. 
Can any one suggest me is there any open source Java `ETL` framework with automatic job scheduling feature.

Thanks & Regards,
Gopal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Jenkins.  Most people use it for deployment and software builds, but honestly it is really a super cron.  It is perfect for periodic jobs.  For ETL use what you think is best: Talend, Clover, Pentaho, scripting language, etc.  Just make sure whatever you package up can be run via the command line so you can use Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

[Jaspersoft ETL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperetl/) provides Job scheduling. Since it is based on Talend, it shouldn't be a difficult for you to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

[CloverETL](http://www.cloveretl.com/) with Server has some job scheduling also.

Maybe you can use Jenkins for scheduling of Talend jobs. (Sounds crazy but I read some article recently about using Jenkins as a scheduling tool ;))

Answer (score 0):

Crazy and perhaps too complicated = smooks + quartz